# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}<2\sqrt n$ by induction

Tags: summation, induction

I am just starting out learning mathematical induction and I got this homework question to prove with induction but I am not managing.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}<2\sqrt n$$
Please help!

Answer (score 5):

One may observe that, for $n>1$,
$$
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k}}
\\&\color{red}{<} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k-1}} 
   \\&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1}}{(\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1})}
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1})
\\& = \sqrt{n}
\end{align}
$$ giving that

> $$
>  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2 \sqrt{n}, \quad n=1,2,3,\cdots.
> $$

Comment: Quote: "prove with induction". (And yes, the other argument is neat.)

Comment: @mari Apparently the OP question has been modified. I think I'm going to leave the *related* answer above.

Comment: Simplifying a telescoping sum uses induction anyway.

Comment: @Bernard Not really, or rather, in a very weak sense: $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k-a_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^na_k-\sum_{k=1}^na_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^na_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+a_n\right)-\left(a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k\right)$$ hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k-a_{k-1}=a_n-a_0$$

Comment: @Did: From a pragmatic point of view, I agree with you. The set theory point of view, even the first equality has induction hidden behind.

Comment: @Bernard Yes I know (see "in a very weak sense") -- but from this point of view the remark becomes so general that it somewhat loses its edge.

Answer (score 2):

*Induction step*

Suppose for some $n\ge1$, one has $\;\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}<2\sqrt n$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{\sqrt k}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}<2\sqrt n+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}. $$
Now 
\begin{align}
2\sqrt n+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}<2\sqrt{n+1}&\iff\frac1{2\sqrt{n+1}} <\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\\
&\iff 2\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\iff\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt n.
\end{align}

*Without induction:*

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}$ is a *lower Riemann sum* for the (improper) Riemann integral $$\displaystyle\int_0^n\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{\sqrt x}=2\sqrt x\,\biggr\rvert_0^n=2\sqrt n.$$